# cypher performance for multiple hops /

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm running my `cypher` queryies on a very large social network (over 1B records). I'm trying to get all paths between two `person` with variable relationship lengths. I get a reasonable response time running a query for a single relationship length (between 0.5 -2 seconds) [the `person` ids are index].

```
MATCH paths=( (pr1:person)-[*0..1]-(pr2:person) )
WHERE pr1.id='123456' 
RETURN paths
```

However when I run the query with multiple lengths (i.e. 2 or more) my response time goes up to several minutes. Assuming that each person has in average the same number of connection I should be running my queries for 2-3 minutes Max (but I get up to 5+ min).

```
MATCH paths=( (pr1:person)-[*0..2]-(pr2:person) )
pr1.id='123456' 
RETURN paths
```

I tried to use the `EXPLAIN` did not show extreme values for the `VarLengthExpand(All)` .
Maybe the traversing is not using the index for the `pr2`.

Is there anyway to improve the performance of my query?

Comment: Depending on the number of results, this might be quite huge for the browser to handle. When you run the query, do you see when resutls start coming back ? There is a line in the Table view with sth like "Started streaming 100 records in less than 1 ms and completed after 1 ms."

Comment: I don't know anything about the `Table view` - can you send me a reference?

Comment: you have on the left of the browser result : Table, Graph, Text. Choose Table

Comment: I'm running the query with `py2neo` , I'll check running the query from the browser

Answer (score 1):

Since variable-length relationship searches have exponential complexity, your `*0..2` query might be generating a very large number of paths, which can cause the neo4j server (or your client code, like the neo4j browser) to run a long time or even run out of memory.

This query might be able to finish and show you how many matching paths there are:

```
MATCH (pr1:person)-[*0..2]-(:person)
WHERE pr1.id='123456' 
RETURN COUNT(*);
```

If the returned number is very large, then you should modify your query to reduce the size of the result. For example, you can adding a [LIMIT](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/limit/) clause after your original `RETURN` clause to limit the number of returned paths.

By the way, the `EXPLAIN` clause just estimates the query cost, and can be way off. The `PROFILE` clause performs the actual query, and gives you an accurate accounting of the DB hits (however, if your query never finishes running, then a `PROFILE` of it will also never finish).

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts. I don't think the problem is the number of the results (it can come back with a few 10k - but we need them all for the analysis). We always get a result but it comes back after 5+ minutes.   I'm trying to improve the performance.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the explain, try the "profile" instead.